# a to z as 1 to 27 encoder in Ruby

Tags: ruby, encoder

Is there any encoding format or standard that satisfies the following conditions?

- A-Z and a-z should be encoded as 1-26.
- Any other character could be greater than 26.

If not, what is the best way to do such conversion?

Hash map is one obvious way, but my ruby intuition says there must be something better.

Comment: Please show the desired output for the string `"aA0�"`.

Comment: What do you need this for?

Comment: *"Any other character could be greater than 26."* -- What does this mean? Does every other character get encoded to 27? I'm guessing so, by the title of your question, but "greater than 26" is an unnecessarily ambiguous requirement.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution that maps the string directly to an `Array` of `Integer`s; making use of the fact that `"a".ord == 97`, `"b".ord == 98`, etc:

```
def encode(str)
  str.each_char.map do |char|
    char.match?(/[a-z]/i) ? c.downcase.ord - 96 : 27
  end
end

encode("aAzZ1&")
#=> [1, 1, 26, 26, 27, 27]
```

Edit: Or similarly, you could perform the `String#downcase` before looping through the characters:

```
def encode(str)
  str.downcase.each_char.map do |char|
    char.match?(/[a-z]/) ? c.ord - 96 : 27
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

`Hash` as a `subst` is good enough since Ruby 2.3 where `Hash#to_proc` was implemented.

```
subst =
  [*?a..?z].zip(1..26).to_h.tap do |h|
    h.default_proc = ->(_, _) { 27 }
  end
"aA0".downcase.each_char.map(&subst)
#⇒ [1, 1, 27]
```

---

or (credits go to @engineersmnky):

```
'a'.upto('z').with_index(1).to_h.tap {|h| h.default = 27 }
```

Comment: Alternatively `'a'.upto('z').with_index(1).to_h.tap {|h| h.default = 27}` and `each_char` might be nicer since `chars` returns an `Array` rather than an `Enumerator`

Answer (score 0):

My option monkey patching the String class.

```
module MyEncoding
  def encode_char_to_int
    letters = [*"a".."z"]
    return letters.index(self.downcase) + 1 if letters.include? self.downcase 
    return 27 # rand(27..255)
  end

  def my_encode
    self.split("").map(&:encode_char_to_int)#.join("")
  end
end

String.include MyEncoding

"aAzZ1&".my_encode #=> [1, 1, 26, 26, 27, 27]
```

Comment: How about `letters.index(self.downcase)&.+(1) || 27`